# How to add attribute without value with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to add the attribute `autoplay` to an iframe.
However, this attribute is only a markup, it does not have a value:

`<iframe src="..." autoplay></iframe`

In Nokogiri to add an attribute its like:

```
iframe = Nokogiri::HTML(iframe).at_xpath('//iframe')
iframe["autoplay"] = ""
puts iframe.to_s

---------- output ----------

"<iframe src="..." autoplay=""></iframe>"
```

Does Nokogiri has such a way to do this or should I remove `/=""/` with an regex at the end?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nokogiri cannot do what you want, out of the box.

- Option 1: use your regex solution.
- Option 2: HTML syntax says that a boolean attribute can be set to its own value, thus this is legal and fine to do in your code:

  ```
  iframe["autoplay"] = "autoplay"
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  <iframe src="..." autoplay="autoplay"></iframe>
  ```
- Option 3: alter the Nokogiri gem code.

  ```
  $ edit nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/html/element_description_defaults.rb
  ```

  Find this line:

  ```
  IFRAME_ATTRS = [COREATTRS, 'longdesc', 'name', ...
  ```

  And insert autoplay:

  ```
  IFRAME_ATTRS = [COREATTRS, 'autoplay', 'longdesc', 'name', ...
  ```

  Now Nokogiri will treat `autoplay` as a binary attribute, as you want.

  I'm creating a pull request for your idea, to add this feature to Nokogiri for everyone:

  https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/pull/1291